# Forcing MAIL FROM envelope to use: authed-user@$mydomain

Tags: postfix

I'm desperately trying to get Postfix to 'rewrite' the MAIL FROM envelope so that it's always in the form of: `authenticated-user@$mydomain`

I've been playing with the `smtpd_sender_login_maps` and `smtpd_sender_restrictions` options but these don't seem to provide anyway of forcing a certain value, merely accepting or rejecting the given value.

How can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### No you can't.

Currently, postfix rewriting feature only doing some mapping like `sender_canonical_maps`. It will rewrite the sender like from `accountA@example.com` to `accountB@example.com`. Also, postfix won't pass the SASL information to rewriting engine.

[You need milter or some kind of content_filter to do that](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.postfix.users/1UH2ldTe0IU/9ugkYgy13bwJ).

> I've been playing with the *smtpd_sender_login_maps* and *smtpd_sender_restrictions* options but these don't seem to provide anyway of forcing a certain value, merely accepting or rejecting the given value.

That's principle design of MTA, it has ACL-like functionality (to reject or permit email). And yes, postfix still has limited rewriting capability. See [Address Rewriting README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html).

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use the generic maps feature. Take a look at:

http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html